# What is a good alternative to using $content_width for image optimization?

Tags: images, optimization, globals

The `$content_width` GLOBAL in WordPress effects many themes and even some plugins by limiting the size of images and embeds in posts, it is a requirement for themes submitted to wordpress.org.

It is set by using:

```
$content_width = 584; // Twenty Twelve example
```

If you insert a large image (default 1024x1024) into a post it results in:

```
src="../wp-content/uploads/2013/02/IMG_1390-1024x682.jpg" width="584" height="328"
```

If instead you remove this global setting and insert the actual image size, set with `add_image_size` it results in:

```
src="../wp-content/uploads/2013/02/IMG_13901-584x328.jpg" width="584" height="328"
```

Removing the global and  inserting large images, *which is very common*, often results in a saving of over 2x, in pages with multiple images I see **hundreds of KB** saved on page load.

Is using `add_image_size` and removing the ability to insert full size images not a better option?

ps. I wrote about [it here](http://wycks.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/why-the-content_width-wordpress-global-kinda-sucks/) with more accurate data

Comment: This sounds like something to bring up on the [wp-hackers](http://lists.automattic.com/mailman/listinfo/wp-hackers) mailing list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `$content_width` global is not only used for images, but also for embedded objects, such as video. So, any solution won't merely be a case of dropping use/support of `$content_width` itself.

Usually a Theme will constrain content-area images in a few ways:

1. **Large** Image size: Defining `$content_width` something appropriate for the Theme design
2. **Original/Full** Image size: Defining a CSS rule for `#content img { max-width: XXX; height: auto; }` to ensure that full-size images that get inserted don't break the layout
3. **Thumbnail** Image size: Calling [`set_post_thumbnail_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size) to define the Featured Image/Post Thumbnail default `thumbnail` size. (Note: I do not personally recommend using this method. Define custom image sizes specific to a given location for a featured image, and then call that custom size in the specific template location, via `the_post_thumbnail( $size )`.)

As you have discovered, because of the way WordPress selects with intermediate image size to use for any given image request, that request could result in a browser-scaled image.

### Theme-Defined Values for Large Image

One option would be to *redefine the settings for large image dimensions*. (Proceed with caution. This is fine for your own site, but a publicly distributed Theme that messes with user configuration settings is... gray area at best.)

The large image dimension settings are stored as:

```
$large_image_width = get_option( 'large_size_w' );
$large_image_height = get_option( 'large_size_h' );
```

So, you could *set* those values according to your `$content_width` value:

```
global $content_width;
update_option( 'large_size_w', $content_width );
update_option( 'large_size_h', $content_width );
```

(Of course, you'd want to put some failsafe/error-checking around this, as appropriate.)

### Remove Option to Insert Full-Sized Images

If you simply want to prevent users from inserting full-size images (again: proceed with caution; this may be Plugin territory), you can filter `'image_size_names_choose'`:

```
function wpse86950_filter_image_size_names_choose( $possible_sizes ) {
    unset( $possible_sizes['full'] );
    return $possible_sizes;
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'wpse86950_filter_image_size_names_choose' );
```

Again: you may want to add some sane failsafes here, as this filter is used in more than one place.

### Define a custom image size for full-post-width images

Related to the previous option, you can define a `'full-post-width'` image size:

```
global $content_width;
add_image_size( 'full-post-width', $content_width, $content_width, false );
```

Then, add it to the list of available options:

```
function wpse86950_filter_image_size_names_choose( $possible_sizes ) {
    // Unset full image size
    unset( $possible_sizes['full'] );
    // Add full-post-width image size
    $possible_sizes['full-post-width'] = 'Full Post Width';
    // Return array
    return $possible_sizes;
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'wpse86950_filter_image_size_names_choose' );
```

Comment: Thanks Chip for the comprehensive answer, I did not think about setting the `get_option` values. The rest is similar to the gist I am using https://gist.github.com/wycks/4949242 that was linked in my link. Also it does seem to be a grey area on how to make this actually scale if the theme is changed.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention removing the `$content_width` or not setting it, it still gets applied by default to embedded objects I think.

Comment: Never saw that `image_size_names_choose` filter until now! I've been that replacing that whole field to get my custom sizes in til now. Is that new in 3.5 Chip?

Comment: I think it's been since 3.3, I've been using it to make the labels of `add_image_size` multilingual, and then I thought it would be also good to use for this image size issue. If you don't need localization you can just smush it into the array instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: @sanchothefat I'm not sure when it was added. Looks like Wyck says it was 3.3? I always love looking through source, when I need to extend/modify something, and finding that a filter has been added to that specific thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes I think so. To get around the `$content_width` issue for themes submitted to the repo I use option filters to force the sizes that I've chosen for the design.

```
add_filter( 'option_large_size_w', function( $opt ) { return 1024; } );
add_filter( 'option_large_size_h', function( $opt ) { return 0; } );
add_filter( 'option_embed_size_w', function( $opt ) { return 1024; } );
add_filter( 'option_embed_size_h', function( $opt ) { return 0; } );
// ...etc...
```