# Image width tag is less than the image pixel width - why?

Tags: media-library, images

I have been reading this morning about images uploaded via the Media Library in WordPress and I thought I had understood most of it. But there's something I'm confused about.

My understanding is that there are a range of default image sizes - `thumbnail`, `medium`, `large` - which are generated when you upload an image. The maximum dimensions are set in your Media / Settings page in the admin panel.

My "Large" sizes are set to the default 1024px wide and 1024px high.

[image: Image sizes]

I have an image which I uploaded that was well over this size. What I'm confused about is when I insert the image into a post and select the large image size - it gives 640px as the width of the image.

[image: Image Details]

The HTML image tag generated on the post is this:

```
<img class="alignnone wp-image-1718 size-large" src="http://www.mysiteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/DSC_7543-1024x767.jpg" alt="DSC_7543" width="640" height="479" />
```

You can clearly see the image is actually 1024px by 767px from the filename - `DSC_7543-1024x767.jpg` - so why is it being scaled to 640px by 479px by the tags?

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

640px is the content size set in your functions.php. Here is an example of the content width set in the bundled theme twentyfourteen in [twentyfourteen/functions.php#L28](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php#L28)

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 474;
}
```

In this example, the image size will be 474 px.

The content size will be the size used when images are inserted as attachments in the content when creating posts

**EDIT**

From the comments from the OP, to remove this restrictions, have a look at the 2 following posts

- [What is a good alternative to using $content_width for image optimization?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/86950/31545)
- [WHY THE $CONTENT_WIDTH WORDPRESS SETTING HURTS OPTIMIZATION.](http://wycks.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/why-the-content_width-wordpress-global-kinda-sucks/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found this in my theme and just changed it to 740px to experiment. The images still had the 640px width until I edited the post and updated the images individually. This seems very labour-intensive! What is the point of `$content_width` if my CSS sets `max-width` of an image to be 100% anyway? It seems restrictive. If I comment that part of my functions.php out will it remove the restriction?

Comment: For reference to anyone else reading this - see this article http://wycks.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/why-the-content_width-wordpress-global-kinda-sucks/ and this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/86950/what-is-a-good-alternative-to-using-content-width-for-image-optimization